# co-option (meaning)

Tags: meaning

Example ([The Kadyrov Factor: Why Putin Must Keep a Close Eye on His Chechen Strongman](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/samuel-ramani/the-kadyrov-factor-why-pu_b_8021240.html?ncid=txtlnkusaolp00000592)):

> Vladimir Putin appointed Kadyrov as Chechen president in 2007 because he wanted a reliable proxy to repress the threat posed by Islamist militants in Chechnya. Kadyrov possessed a fully formed militia, known as the Kadyrovtsy, which assisted Russian efforts to consolidate control over the North Caucasus. Kadyrov's ability to combine brutal repression with the **co-option** of the Qadiriya (a leading Sufi Muslim sect) made him a vital component of Putin's imperial grand design in the CIS region.

Could you please explain in simplest terms possible what *co-option* is exactly?

Comment: I don't know the details of the situation, but check Wikipedia [***co-option***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-option) #2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *co-opt* something is to "divert to or use in a role different from the usual or original one."  So, Kadriyov's co-option of the Qadiriya refers to his gaining control of the sect, most likely to put it to use to further Putin's political ends.